# How does Ceres::Solve call the Problem::Evaluate?

Tags: c++, ceres-solver

As I am reading the ceres source codes, I could not find the how the function calls  navigate from "[ceres::Solve](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/blob/master/internal/ceres/solver.cc#L832)"  to ["Problem::Evaluate"](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/blob/master/internal/ceres/problem.cc#L128) ?

Anyone knows?

Thanks.

Want to know the detail how `ceres::Solve` calls the `Problem::Evaluate` eventually?

Comment: Recommendation: Build a simple test case, compile the library and test case for debug and then step through the test case with a debugger and watch the process happen as it happens. Very educational.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.